# How to get shipping address pincode inside shipment tab in magento

Tags: magento

I am developing a custome shipping mehtod in mageto, for rate api i need current customer's shipping address (pincode), in shipment tab please help

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking like this...

```
<?php
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
?>
```